# How to List all Talend jobs Running

Tags: talend

Is there a way to list all the running talend jobs in the server?
I'm currently relying to yarn management to check.

Appreciate all your help.

Comment: You should ask that on Talend Forum instead, this would be a tool provided with the studio or in the TAC. Either way, this is off-topic to ask about tools or external resource on SO.

Comment: Which server? Which version? Do you know about the *Talend Administration Center MetaServlet API*?

Answer (score 0):

each talend job runs a process on jvm, so either ps aux | grep java or jps should give you this, you can then change the grep part of this and create a bash script / cron job this to automate as required